# python regexp for a few thousand words

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to find certain keywords in a string with python. The string is something like this:

```
A was changed from B to C
```

all **I'm trying to find is the "to C" part**, where **C is one of many thousand words**.

This code builds the regexp string:

```
pre_pad = 'to '
regex_string = None
for i in words:
    if regex_string == None:
        regex_string = '\\b%s%s(?!-)(?!_)\\b' %(pre_pad, i)
    else:
        regex_string = regex_string + '|\\b%s%s(?!-)(?!_)\\b' %(pre_pad, i)
```

And later on I do:

```
matches = []
for match in re.finditer(r"%s" %regex_string, text):
        matches.append([match, MATCH_TYPE])
```

This code works on linux but crashes on macos with ***"Caught OverflowError while rendering: regular expression code size limit exceeded"***

I realize that the regex_string is very long and that this is the cause of the problem

```
print regex_string.__len__()
63574
```

how can I fix this so this will always work, independent of the number of words?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that the pre_pad is sometimes empty: pre_pad = '', so searching for pre_pad first is not always possible.

In addition to that, the reason why I build the entire regex_string first and then match it against the words is that I have to do this matching for many thousand entries. If I had to build the regex_string every single time again, this would lead to very poor performance.

Oh, and I need to know which word matches.

Comment: It should never have even occurred to you to do this with a regex, what you're describing is not even remotely like what regexes are for. Just split the string on spaces and iterate through the words checking against a `set` or `dict` of the desired keywords.

Comment: Why would it be slower? set and dict lookups are, by design, extremely fast (and must be, virtually everything you do in Python depends on a dict in some way), and I just split a 28MB string into a list of 4 million elements in approximately 1 second. Just how ginormous are your strings? Premature optimization accomplishes nothing but wasting valuable developer time, and usually ends up giving you sub-optimal code anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supposed to be a task you can solve with a huge regexp and expect better performances than this:

```
pre_pad = 'to '
matches = []

for i in words:
    regex_string = '\\b%s%s(?!-)(?!_)\\b' % (pre_pad, i)
    for match in re.finditer(r"%s" % regex_string, text):
        matches.append([match, MATCH_TYPE])
```

Also if, **after profiling** your code you see chained regexp work faster calculate your regexp string length while building it and split the full task in 2, 3, 10 to avoid overflow.

P.S.:

```
print len(regex_string)
```

is more pythonic...

Comment: I forgot to mention that the pre_pad is sometimes empty: pre_pad = '', so searching for pre_pad first is not always possible. In addition to that, the reason why I build the entire regex_string first and then match is against the words is that I have to do this matching for many thousand entries. If I had to build the regex_string every single time again, this would lead to very poor performance.

Comment: @memyself: I can't get the `pre_pad` problem anyway my suggestion was to make a regex for each word or split the big one in chunks. Then fix the code accordingly. About very poor performances: **did you profile to be sure about that**? What's the performance loss in percentage and time?

Comment: your solution runs ~ 1000 times slower than my solution. that is because words is a few thousand words.

Comment: @ did you also tried splitting your big regex in chunkes that do not overflow? 1000 times slower anyway? Don't think so. Anyway I agree with Nicholas Knight that this is not a regex task. Moreover about my code above can you post profiling results to see where's the bottleneck? See here an example of [quick and good profiling](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract C from your input by a simple regex and then look it up in a structure optimised for searching:

- some tree
- ordered list with binary search
- hash structure (like python's `set`)

Something like

```
return match_from_regex in set_of_words
```

Comment: This is basically the updated aix's solution. I missed the update when posting my answer.

Comment: that only works is pre_pad is not empty. if pre_pad is empty, then I still have to match every single word C.

Comment: What's the problem? Just extract the word to check by a regex with empty pre_pad and then look it up.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem a little differently to be honest. I would make a words map (which I can check if the word exists with O(1) complexity). then search for all " to [\w]+ " regex for getting every "to" matches in the big text. then for every match I would check if it exists in words map. Would be much more efficient I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as stated appears to lend itself very well to a non-regex solution.

Alternatively, iterate over matches for `r'\b%s(\B+)(?!-)(?!_)\b' % pre_pad`, and check that the word matched by the first group is in your dictionary.

Comment: @Krab: Well, do a linear scan looking for `pre_pad` ('to '), and then check what's immediately before and after it.

Comment: this will only work if pre_pad is not empty. But I also have cases where pre_pad is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python expert, so my answer is not authoritative. However, it seems to me that regex is not the best tool in this case. If the structure of the string

```
A was changed from B to C
```

is fixed, then isn't it sufficient to use the [`in`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in) operator iterating over the words that you want to check:

```
>>> "to blue" in "A was changed from red to blue"
True
```