# Tagging words based on a dictionary/list in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following dictionary of gene names:

```
gene_dict = {"repA1":1, "leuB":1} 
# the actual dictionary is longer, around ~30K entries. 
# or in list format 
# gene_list = ["repA1", "leuB"]
```

What I want to do is given any sentence, we search for terms that is contained in the above dictionary and then tagged them.

For example given this sentence:

```
mytext = "xxxxx repA1 yyyy REPA1 zzz."
```

It will be then tagged as:

```
xxxxx <GENE>repA1</GENE> yyyy <GENE>REPA1</GENE> zzz.
```

Is there any efficient way to do that? In practicality we would process couple of millions of sentences.

Comment: Looks like the task is easily parallelizable. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842237/parallel-processing-in-python . You could use `Pool` to parallelize the task locally or something like mincemeatpy to utilize a map-reduce server.

Answer (score 3):

If you "gene_list" in not really-really-really long, you could use a compiled regular expression, like

```
import re

gene_list = ["repA1", "leuB"]
regexp = re.compile('|'.join(gene_list), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
result = re.sub(regexp, r'<GENE>\g<0></GENE>', 'xxxxx repA1 yyyy REPA1 zzz.')
```

and put in a loop for all your sentences. I think this should be quite fast.

Comment: # the actual dictionary is longer, around ~30K entries.

Comment: If there are 30k entries, then you might be better off iterating through the list of entries in the dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276796/python-regexp-for-a-few-thousand-words . The performance depends on data (how densely/sparsely the genes are present in the sentences etc), so profiling should give you some useful hints.

Comment: It seems that the number of entries is much higher vs the size of the sentence. It would be indeed better to use a Set() to check for gene membership. Although breaking down the sentence into words will also add to the load. As @jpe said, I suggest you do some code profiling and run some tests.

Answer (score 1):

If *most* of the sentences are short and separated by single spaces, something like:

```
gene_dict = {"repA1":1, "leuB":1}
format_gene = "<GENE>{}</GENE>".format

mytext = " ".join(format_gene(word) if word in gene_dict else word for word in mytext.split())
```

is going to be faster.

For slightly longer sentences or sentences you cannot reform with `" ".join` it might be more efficient or more correct to use several `.replace`s:

```
gene_dict = {"repA1":1, "leuB":1}
genes = set(gene_dict)
format_gene = "<GENE>{}</GENE>".format

to_replace = genes.intersection(mytext.split())

for gene in to_replace:
    mytext = mytext.replace(gene, format_gene(gene))
```

Each of these assume that `split`s of the sentences will not take extortionate time, which is fair assuming `genes_dict` is a much longer than the sentences.

Comment: `genes = set(genes)` do you mean `genes = set(gene_dict)`

Comment: your code only tagged the first word `xxxxx <GENE>repA1</GENE> yyyy REPA1 zzz.` How can I make it more general to make it case-insenstive?

Comment: Well that complicates things... :). Before I fix it, which one is faster (so which should I improve)?